# having problem while creating view. i want to combine few tables that have similar column name but diffrent data

Tags: sql, ssis

i have this code and i keep getting error Msg 4506, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Mortgage_view10, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 4]
Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'MonthlyIncome' in view or function 'Mortgage_view10' is specified more than once.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQWjp.png)

Comment: Edit your question and include the code *as text* in the question.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what it should be doing would also help.

Comment: Looking ar your image - that should be text in your question - I note that you really need to learn to use *meaningful* table aliases and structure your queries in a more easily-readable format. Selecting `*` is an anti-pattern at the best of times, in  a *view* you *must* use `with schema binding` or any changes to the underlying table will break your view. It's also going to be the cause of your error.